# Github webpage - Error 404 file not found

Tags: github, error-handling

I have created a personal website and committed it to Github. It has several pages. The problem is with one of them: when I load it in locahost, it works, but it doesn't when I try to load it in github.

The link to my github repository is https://github.com/Econres/eS_MiData

The page/file that doesn't work is https://econres.github.io/eS_MiData/app/metadatos.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name in the URL is [case sensitive](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90378/92089). Since the file is `METADATOS.html`, using the link [`https://econres.github.io/eS_MiData/app/METADATOS.html`](https://econres.github.io/eS_MiData/app/METADATOS.html) fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem !